# Why has my question about the Einstein field equation been closed?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, homework-and-exercises, close-reasons

I would not have wanted to write this. In fact, I am so sorry of the fact that many times some questions are not considered as they are too stupid.

My question *[Scalar curvature is $0$ for Schwarzschild solution](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/625855/)*  has been closed soon after writing and submitting it. I have not understood why...in effect I have tried to show my work and in the comments I have understood that my work is wrong.

So my question is: does failing a work imply a question closed? I would have hoped that an attempt of work could have been appreciated and someone could tell me how solve my mistakes.

Comment: Please read the meta post linked in the closing notice (that this post is now also a duplicate of) - just showing your work is not sufficient for making a question on-topic here, we want questions to ask *conceptual* questions that are more than "how do I proceed with this computation?".

Comment: I have explained why I am interested to derive that result and I have written down my procedement. It has been tagged with "homework and excercise"...I have not presented my question as a huge dillemma...what i have to do in addition?

Comment: Nik, do you have access to Landau volume 2?  See this link for the google books: https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Classical_Theory_of_Fields.html?id=X18PF4oKyrUC  What is your native language by the way, I can provide a much better reference than whatever textbook you are using right now and explain what page the answer is in so you can figure out how to phrase the answer to your problem which you are really close to solving I promise!

Comment: @MattCalhoun Thanks a lot! I will try to find the book that you suggest! A very kind user has helped in the comments (a little difficult so) me even if the question has been closed and as you can see in the edit I have reached the solution! Thanks for the help that you has offered! I appreciate it so much

Comment: Nik, no problem!  Make sure to get Landau vol 2 and check the chapter where the answer is like a one liner.  Cheers!